# alias table with union all not works

Tags: sql, oracle, column-alias

I have ora-00094 (identifier not valid) in a simple query but I can't see why. Could you help me please?

```
select columnA, 'More than 4000 bytes'
from tableA

union all

select  p.columnB, listagg(p.columnC, ',') within group (order by p.columnC)
from (            
  select distinct b.job_name, a.hostname
  from tableB a, emuser.def_job b
) p   
group by p.columnB 
order by p.columnB desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY is for ResultSet of whole query. So for ORDER BY there is no columnB here. ResultSet have only column names of first query.

Try this

```
SELECT columnA, 'More than 4000 bytes' as columnC  FROM tableA
UNION ALL
  SELECT p.columnB, LISTAGG (p.columnC, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.columnC)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT b.job_name, a.hostname
            FROM tableB a, emuser.def_job b) p
GROUP BY p.columnB
ORDER BY p.columnA DESC;
```